# Make type of object from array of strings

Tags: typescript

There is converting an array of strings into object:

```js
const myFields = ['field1', 'field2'];
const myObject = myFields.reduce((obj, fld) => ({ ...obj, [fld]: `val of ${fld}` }), {});
```

In this case type of `myObject` will be `{}` and access to `myObject.field1` will be displayed with error.

**How to make actual type from array of strings?**

Like:

```js
type MyObject = {
  field1: string,
  field2: string
};
```

Comment: ① Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] without typos/pseudocode; try testing it in an IDE and making sure it does what you want it to do. ② Once you do that, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mq00kN) meet your needs? TS is not clever enough to know what computed keys will do to the output type, nor can it represent the progressive modification of a type in `reduce()`; the closest you'll get is a type assertion. If that fully addresses the question I will write an answer or find a suitable dupe target. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, thanks for answer, it's complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to make actual type from array of strings?

You can't, with the array you've shown. The array's values would have to be known at compile-time, like this:

```
const myFields = ['field1', 'field2'] as const;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^
```

If they aren't, then you can't definitely type the object, since you need to know what those values are to define the type, and the type only exists at compile-time.

If you can't do that, you're pretty much stuck with `Record<string, string>`.

If you *can* add the `as const` so the array values are known at compile-time, then you can define the type of the object as `Record<typeof myFields[number], string>`, which picks out the values of the array (tuple) as property names and uses them in a record where their values will be strings. The code would look like this:

```
const myFields = ['field1', 'field2'] as const;
const myObject = myFields.reduce(
    (obj, fld) => ({ ...obj, [fld]: `val of ${fld}` }),
    {} as Record<typeof myFields[number], string>
);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGIEsCmAbAJhGBeGAbQHIAzdbARmIBoYyKsAmYgXRgENdRIoBuAFA9o8BAHkARgCs0wWAUSpMOAHQAnNFgCuwNAAoBMIzD0hpdUtgCU+AHwmA3jBUuzUuoUtZWALhgADADcODBgQUhgAEgcvAF9-GFirGkNjB1jOXAAlWRA1LAAeKAQABzRw0SVsCEIwLTgJNDVWOmg1FDAAc1sBK0EhcAgQDDQVDBBOvURJGTkVcmVKPoHIYdHxyenpWSh5xiZloA)

(There's a small lie there we get away with [initially, `{}` isn't a valid `Record<typeof myFields[number], string>`], but it's no longer a lie once the `reduce` is complete.)

After the above, this would be valid code:

```
console.log(myObject.field1);
console.log(myObject.field2);
```

But again, that only works when the array is a compile-time constant.

---

Side note: You'll notice I added `()` around the expression body of your arrow function, since otherwise the leading `{` means you're writing a full function body, not an expression function body.